# How to filter the most voted question in last month/week/since last visit

Tags: support, search

I would like to read the most voted questions in some time for my favorite tags, is there a way how to filter it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=intags%3amine%20created%3a4d..+score%3A5
```

Change the 4d for something else, it has post that are less than 4 days old. There's simply no way to know when you last visited (at least not exposed).

Comment: Thanks. Did not found this before http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in the beta version of Stack Overflow.

**For Beta Only**

Make a new tab, sort it by votes and time period, and type in the tags you wish to see, then click save. If you want *all* of your tags it may take a little time to enter but it will be only once.

---

**Step 1**

*click on* <kbd>+ new tab</kbd>

[image]

---

**Step 2**

*click on the updown arrow button (sort) and select "votes"*

[image]

---

**Step 3**

*click on the funnel button (filter) and select "month" (or your preference)*

[image]

---

**Step 4**

*type in your favorite tags and don't forget to **save***

[image]

Comment: This sounds great, but please, where is this [+new tab] button...? I am looking for it in profile, on homepage etc... I am probably just blind

Comment: I believe this is only available if you've opted in to the new nav beta.

Comment: Thanks @resueman, I have opted in preferences, but no tabs available, number of users with beta is probably limited.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize this was still only an option in the beta version.